# Using Cookie in Perl

Tags: perl, cookies, httpclient

I want to use Cookie in Perl but i have a problem . 
it's my code :

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies;
$xpl = new LWP::UserAgent(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.5) Gecko/20060719 Firefox/1.5.0.5');
$req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://example.com') or die "\n\n Failed to Connect, Try again!\n"; 
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new(file => 'cookie.txt');
$xpl->cookie_jar($cookie_jar);
$res = $xpl->request($req);
print $xpl->request($req)->as_string;
```

and the content of cookie.txt is : 0fea8e55a89187d306d7db060b7b9ab7 . and when i runing this code i get this warning : cookie.txt does not seem to contain cookies at F:/Perl/lib/HTTP/Cookies.pm line 432,  line 1.

what am i going to do ? 
Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1):

The content of `cookies.txt` is supposed to be a file generated by `HTTP::Cookies` describing cookie names, values, domains, and expirations. The file you're giving it isn't in the format it uses, so it's not being loaded.

Comment: ok . i change this txt file : 'SESSIONID','/','www.ex.com','fea8e55a89187d306d7db060b7b9ab7' but i get the same error !!!

Comment: That's not the format which `HTTP::Cookies` uses either. Use `HTTP::Cookies` to generate the file rather than trying to guess the format yourself.

Comment: may you give me an example about HTTP::Cookies and the content of cookie.txt . Thanks